# Check a checkbox if variable is equal to string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am displaying a checkbox in a modal dialog. I use ajax to retrieve a database model with one of the variables returned being `data.admin`. When this variable equals the string "A" the checkbox must be shown as checked. Otherwise it should remain unchecked.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="admin" name="admin">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="admin">Admin</label>
</div> 

$(document).on('click', '.edit_data',function(){
    var id_code = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"edit.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{id_code:id_code},
        datatype:"json",
        success:function(data){
            $('#code').val(data.code);
            $('#login').val(data.login);
            $('#pass').val(data.pass);
            $('#admin').val(data.admin);
            $('#id_code').val(data.id);
            $('#myModale').modal("show");  
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a checkbox in jQuery by using the `prop` function:

```
$('#admin').prop('checked', true); // use false to uncheck
```

So in your case you'll need to check the variable using an if statement, and then check the checkbox as required:

```
if(data.admin === "A") {
    $('#admin').prop('checked', true);
}
else {
    $('#admin').prop('checked', false);
}
```

Use the above the code instead of the line `$('#admin').val(data.admin);`

EDIT: As Jeto says in a comment below:

> Can be shortened to `$('#admin').prop('checked', data.admin === 'A');`

Comment: Can be shortened to `$('#checkbox').prop('checked', data.admin === 'A');`